# Is it possible to use android's speech recognition without showing the dialog?

Tags: android

I want to use the speech to text api in android, but I don't want to be slowed down by those dialogs. Is it possible to use the functionality without them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use speech recognition without the annoying dialog in android phones](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316937/how-can-i-use-speech-recognition-without-the-annoying-dialog-in-android-phones)

Answer (score 23):

Yes it is possible:

You can use the SpeechRecognizer class from the API.
Make sure it is used in the main thread - as required according to the API - and that your class implements the RecognitionListener.

```
private SpeechRecognizer speech;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    speech = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
    speech.setRecognitionListener(this);

    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, "en");
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,
        this.getPackageName());

    speech.startListening(intent);
}

@Override
public void onBeginningOfSpeech()
{
}

@Override
public void onBufferReceived(byte[] arg0)
{
}

@Override
public void onEndOfSpeech()
{
}

@Override
public void onError(int e)
{
}

@Override
public void onEvent(int arg0, Bundle arg1)
{
}

@Override
public void onPartialResults(Bundle arg0)
{
}

@Override
public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle arg0)
{
}

@Override
public void onResults(Bundle data)
{
    ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayList(
        SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);

    // Do something useful with the matches =)
    // ...
}

@Override
public void onRmsChanged(float arg0)
{
}
```

Comment: this will recognise speech only first time, how to continuos recognising speech....

Comment: @PradeepSodhi did u figure it out pradeep? Please let me know! 

Comment: You could call speech.startListening(...) again, if you defined the intent to be provided and the SpeechRecognizer within the class, instead of the onCreate method. (I'm not using speech anymore, so it's just a guess.)

Comment: i geting some error W/ActivityManager: Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@2c8ad3c9
03-03 03:46:53.253 749-847/? E/lights: write_int failed to open -1
03-03 03:46:53.433 749-960/? W/ActivityManager: mDVFSHelper.acquire()
03-03 03:46:53.453 11941-11959/? W/MessageQueue: Handler (com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler) {cdd48b4} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread

Answer (score 8):

try this code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.speech.RecognitionListener;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.speech.SpeechRecognizer;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class VoiceRecognitionActivity extends Activity implements RecognitionListener {

    private TextView returnedText;
    private ToggleButton toggleButton;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private SpeechRecognizer speech = null;
    private Intent recognizerIntent;
    private String LOG_TAG = "VoiceRecognitionActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_voice_recognition);
        returnedText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        toggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        speech = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
        speech.setRecognitionListener(this);
        recognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE,"en");
        recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,this.getPackageName());
        recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_WEB_SEARCH);
        recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 3);

        toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
                    speech.startListening(recognizerIntent);
                } else {
                    progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    speech.stopListening();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (speech != null) {
            speech.destroy();
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "destroy");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onBeginningOfSpeech");
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressBar.setMax(10);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onBufferReceived: " + buffer);
    }

    @Override
    public void onEndOfSpeech() {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onEndOfSpeech");
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        toggleButton.setChecked(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(int errorCode) {
        String errorMessage = getErrorText(errorCode);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "FAILED " + errorMessage);
        returnedText.setText(errorMessage);
        toggleButton.setChecked(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onEvent");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPartialResults(Bundle arg0) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onPartialResults");
    }

    @Override
    public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle arg0) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onReadyForSpeech");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResults(Bundle results) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onResults");
        ArrayList<String> matches = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
        String text = "";
        for (String result : matches)
            text += result + "\n";

        returnedText.setText(text);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onRmsChanged: " + rmsdB);
        progressBar.setProgress((int) rmsdB);
    }

    public static String getErrorText(int errorCode) {
        String message;
        switch (errorCode) {
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_AUDIO:
            message = "Audio recording error";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_CLIENT:
            message = "Client side error";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSIONS:
            message = "Insufficient permissions";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NETWORK:
            message = "Network error";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NETWORK_TIMEOUT:
            message = "Network timeout";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NO_MATCH:
            message = "No match";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_RECOGNIZER_BUSY:
            message = "RecognitionService busy";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_SERVER:
            message = "error from server";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_SPEECH_TIMEOUT:
            message = "No speech input";
            break;
        default:
            message = "Didn't understand, please try again.";
            break;
        }
        return message;
    }

}
```

activity_voice_recognition.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toggleButton1"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="47dp" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:text="ToggleButton" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.rakesh.voicerecognitionexample"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/> 
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name=".VoiceRecognitionActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_voice_recognition" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

No.

[The Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html) for the speech recognition displays the dialog and there are no options to disable showing it.

You should also know that the speech recognition feature requires an internet connection so that the sound can be uploaded to Google for recognition.

Comment: What about Google API?? Does it exist as a webservice to convert audio to text?  If so, is that what the Android's intent uses??

Comment: I'm pretty sure the thing about needing to connect to the internet is wrong. I turned wifi off my device and put it into wifi mode, and it still worked. If you use FREE_FORM for the RecognitionIntent, it shouldn't require internet.

Comment: http://www.truiton.com/2014/06/android-speech-recognition-without-dialog-custom-activity/