# Android SpeechToText STT Dialog

Tags: java, android, dialog, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

Is there any way to hide the dialog box that shows up when using Speech to Text in android? I have read somewhere it is impossible but surely there must be a way to at the very least show it then hide it immediately?

Maybe some way of subclassing something and altering the look of it? In my app I still want an indicator of the speech being encoded but not using the dialog box that google gives as standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identical question: [Is it possible to use android's speech recognition without showing the dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703148/is-it-possible-to-use-androids-speech-recognition-without-showing-the-dialog)